# Get all selected values from child component

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I have rendered a component that has select dropdowns multiple times on a button click event.

```
class AppComponent extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
 super(props); 

this.state = {
  numChildren: 0
}
this.onAddChild = this.onAddChild.bind(this);
}

render () {
  const children = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < this.state.numChildren; i += 1) {
    children.push(<ChildComponent key={i} number={i} />);
  };

  return (
    <ParentComponent addChild={this.onAddChild} submit={this.submitData}>
      {children}
    </ParentComponent>
  );
}

submitData(){
console.log("Submit Data button");

}

onAddChild() {
  this.setState({
    numChildren: this.state.numChildren + 1
  });
}
}
```

ParentComponent is adding childcomponent on onClick event.

```
const ParentComponent = props => (
<div className="card calculator">
<button onClick={props.addChild}>Add Another Child 
Component</button>
<button onClick={props.submit}>Submit Data</button>

  {props.children}
</div>
);
const ChildComponent = props => < NewComponent />;

class NewComponent extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state = { 
first: null,
second: null,
third : null,
}
this.changeFirst = this.changeFirst.bind(this);
this.changeSecond = this.changeSecond.bind(this);
this.changeThird = this.changeThird.bind(this);
}

changeFirst(e) {
this.setState({
first : e.target.value
});

}
 changeSecond(e) {
this.setState({
second : e.target.value
});
}
 changeThird(e) {
this.setState({
third : e.target.value
});
}



render (){


return (
<div>
<select onChange={this.changeFirst}>
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
<option value = "Mahindra"> Mahindra</option>
<option value = "Car"> Car</option>
</select>
<select onChange={this.changeSecond}>
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
<option value = "Mahindra"> Mahindra</option>
  <option value = "Car"> Car</option>
</select>
<select onChange={this.changeThird}>
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
<option value = "Mahindra"> Mahindra</option>
  <option value = "Car"> Car</option>
</select>
</div>
);
}


}
```

NewComponent is getting rendered as childcomponent when button is clicked.
I have added changeFirst, changeSecond and changeThird custom functions to handle change event and set state of NewComponent (child component).

What I want to do is, I want to get list of all selected values of each child component instance.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please show some relevant code. Your question is way, way too vague to provide any meaningful answers.

Comment: I have updated question and added exact code.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create a wrapper component( common parent) and add there a list in the state where you are going to have all the selected options of the 3 dropdowns.
2. Create a callback function in charge of update the list of selected options.
3. pass this callback to the children (3 dropdowns)
4. in the dropdowns onChange = your callback

Comment: I am new to React, I didn't get you actually... can you explain more ?